# How do I prevent CSS border from shrinking my div?

Tags: css

When opening my dialog using the "Open" button, you can see that the content is not shrinking.

However, when opening it with the "Open Modal" button, the content is shrinking. How can I prevent this? I do not want a solution where I need to add `white-space: nowrap;` or other properties to every single thing inside the dialog, I am looking for a generic solution which will make the modal dialog behave like the modeless one.

PS: I am doing things the way I do them because I am working on a fallback for the dialog element. So I cannot just use the dialog element and I ideally do not want to add extra markup.

```js
const dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");

document.getElementById("open").addEventListener("click", () => {
    dialog.classList.add("open");
});

document.getElementById("openModal").addEventListener("click", () => {
    dialog.classList.add("open", "modal");
});

document.getElementById("close").addEventListener("click", () => {
    dialog.classList.remove("open", "modal");
});
```

```css
.dialog {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: salmon;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.dialog.modal {
    border-width: max(100vh, 100vw);
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
}
.dialog.open {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog" id="dialog">
  <p>This is my dialog box</p>
  <button id="close">Close</button>
</div>

<button id="open">Open</button>

<button id="openModal">Open Modal</button>
```

Comment: do you know why you are using `border-width: max(100vh, 100vw);` and what's its meaning?

Comment: One option could be to give `.dialog` an explicit `min-width` value (e.g. `150px`).

Comment: @DiegoD What do you mean? I am using it to get the backdrop effect and set the width so that it guaranteed will cover the entire screen regardless of screen orientation/size

Comment: you are setting the border width of your div as large as the whole viewport!! do you know about the box model? what do you expect? why the content is shrinking?

Comment: @DiegoD Is there a way to make the border not shrink the content?

Comment: By the way, seems like ```width: max-content;``` did the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, using border in this way isn't "normal" to begin with. It's much more common and less problematic to simply use a pseudo-element to create the mask.

Because text is free to wrap, and because you've given your border fluid sizing, the border fills the space that's not otherwise allocated (the largest space that allows the longest word in your text).

I suggest you take a more conventional approach and use a mask element instead. Note that I've applied z-index to the dialog to keep it over the mask.

```js
const dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");

document.getElementById("open").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.classList.add("open");
});

document.getElementById("openModal").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.classList.add("open", "modal");
  document.body.classList.add('modal-open');
});

document.getElementById("close").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.classList.remove("open", "modal");
  document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
});
```

```css
.dialog {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: salmon;
  padding: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

body.modal-open::after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
}

.dialog.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog" id="dialog">
  <p>This is my dialog box</p>
  <button id="close">Close</button>
</div>

<button id="open">Open</button>

<button id="openModal">Open Modal</button>
```

Comment: This is more normal and probably a better approach indeed. I am however doing things the way I do them because I am making a fallback to the dialog element and wanted to simulate using ::backdrop without the need of other elements. If you open 2 dialogs for example the backdrops will not stack or hide the previous dialog in this solution. But I might just use this solution anyways because fallbacks dont need to be perfect I guess

Comment: What is "a fallback for the dialog element"? Fallback to what? You shouldn't be allowing multiple dialogs anyway. It's a bad UX.

Comment: Incase the dialog element is not supported @isherwood and I dont believe it is bad UX. E.g. You can have a dialog side menu open which reveals an option to change language which opens a dialog box on top.

Comment: The dialog element [is supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=dialog) by any browser _you_ should be supporting. Also, a sidebar is a different thing than we're discussing here, but it can still cause accessibility problems if visually-impaired users can't keep track of where you've sent them.

Comment: anyone using Safari pre 2022 does not have dialog elements (~1.5%) small, but still, figured I'd add a quick little something for it.

Comment: So I decided that I will just make the dialog fallback always be modeless due to stacking context issues I noticed with non JS solutions but I'll mark this as accepted because it seems to be the best solution to a fake backdrop

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a dialog, use the [dialog HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog). This also provides you with an out of the box way to style the background.

For this simple example, I added a check if the dialog is already shown before opening the modal, otherwise it would throw an error.

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");

document.getElementById("open").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.show();
});

document.getElementById("openModal").addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (dialog.open) { 
    dialog.close()
  }
  dialog.showModal();
});

document.getElementById("close").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.close();
});
```

```css
dialog {
  background: salmon;
  /*background color for the dialog + modal*/
}


/*
some fancy gradient for the backdrop!
*/

::backdrop {
  background-image: linear-gradient( 45deg, magenta, rebeccapurple, dodgerblue, green);
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<dialog>
  <p>This is my dialog box</p>
  <button type="button" id="close">Close</button>
</dialog>

<button id="open">Open</button>

<button id="openModal">Open Modal</button>
```

Comment: I am working on a fallback for the dialog element, I should've mentioned that.

Comment: google already created a polyfill for the dialog element, there you can see how this can be done: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill